# How to create responsive line graph in React Native

Tags: react-native

[image: How to create responsive line graph] to show stock exchange kind of information.. With 1 day 1week 1 month window

like below screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a package like this:

https://github.com/wuxudong/react-native-charts-wrapper